# How to get the value of the index of *ngFor outside the loop?

Tags: angular

here is my loop:

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items; let rowcount = index'></div>
<div>showing {{ rowcount }} of {{ items.length }}
```

But rowcount is showing NOTHING. Any suggestion on how I can get the value of rowcount correctly?

Comment: why do you need this? your `rowcount` will be visually the same as `items.length`

Comment: The concept of index does not exist outside a loop (index of what element would it be ?)

Comment: @YaroslavGrishajev  i want to show how many records have been displayed out of the total items. Example 30 out of 500. This is for pagination purposes. If I am on the last page, and the last page has only 30 items remaining and my maximum items per page is 100.

Comment: in you example `rowcount === items.length` if it was designed like that. You should look for another approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this, just need to display it **after** the last item.

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items; let rowcount = index'>
    <!-- Do all your stuff here -->

    <div *ngIf="last">showing {{ rowcount }} of {{ items.length }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! Alright! I wasn't sure it would work, I've never used the `last` before, thats awesome! Glad to help out!